# how to refresh content of safari extensions popover

Tags: safari-extension

How can I refresh the content of a safari extensions popover, so that everything in the window is loaded over?

If you're interested in relation to what, I need the content to reload everytime the tabbar icon is clicked, so that multiple tabs do not share the same popover.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `window.location.reload()` from the context of the popover, or `safari.extension.popovers[0].contentWindow.location.reload()` (assuming it's the first popover) from the context of the global page.

Comment: yup - that's exactly what I needed, especially the second line was really useful to me :)